# Any AJAX or dynamic content e.g. dialog or poll giving exception that response already committed

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, wildfly

I have a simple dialog and a button to call it. Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:form id="loginForm">

            <p:commandLink onclick="PF('dlg').show()" value="Test"/>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

    <p:dialog header="Header Text" widgetVar="dlg">Content</p:dialog>

</h:body>
</html>
```

the dialog is opening but giving exception as follows:

```
19:47:40,488 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionH
andler] (default task-2) Could not handle exception!: java.lang.IllegalStateExce
ption: UT010019: Response already commited
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.resetBuffer(ServletO
utputStreamImpl.java:738)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.reset(HttpServletRes
ponseImpl.java:523)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.reset(ServletResponseWrapper.jav
a:238)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.reset(ServletResponseWrapper.jav
a:238)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.responseReset(ExternalConte
xtImpl.java:1104)
        at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.han
dleAjaxException(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:150)
        at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.han
dle(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:97)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:118)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHand
ler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(F
ilterHandler.java:129)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61
)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(F
ilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandle
r.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.hand
leRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChai
n.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(
ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
rvletInitialHandler.java:274)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(Ser
vletInitialHandler.java:209)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDis
patcherImpl.java:221)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(Reque
stDispatcherImpl.java:147)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatc
herImpl.java:111)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61
)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(F
ilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandle
r.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.hand
leRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChai
n.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(
ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHan
dler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandle
r.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandle
r.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRe
quest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstrain
tHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleR
equest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandl
er.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleReque
st(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandl
er.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.han
dleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHand
ler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest
(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(Servlet
InitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInit
ialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInit
ialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.cal
l(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(Context
ClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAct
ion.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
rvletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(Servlet
InitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(Se
rvletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)

        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:8
30)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLo
aderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor
.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(Enhanced
QueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueE
xecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using Wildfly 14 and Primefaces 5.2.24. I have also tried it with Primefaces 6.0. It is also doing the same for primefaces poll and throwing this same exception. Seems like it is throwing for all kind of ajax or dynamic components of primefaces. Also doing the same on Wildfly 16.

Comment: I have a deja vu...

Comment: yes explaining the same question. And providing the minimal, complete and verifiable example for you to test and verify. Creating this simple xhtml page will generate this exception.

Comment: and same exception on new primefaces version like 6.0 too. on 7.0, its saying:
Unrecognized Content Type.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Content Type.

Comment: But where is your other question then? And what if you remove the `f:view` and what if you use JSF 2.3 namespaces? And why is there no action in the `p:commandButton`

Comment: And what if you don't use prettyfaces? (stacktrace shows you are using it)

Comment: tried by removing prettyfaces and the command button is only for javascript function call so no action is there

Comment: For the commandButton, check the PrimeFaces documentation about it, especially the type attribute